# Refinancing a mortgage: Can I use an appraisal ordered by a previous lender with a new one?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, refinance, appraisal

My wife and I are currently in the process of refinancing our home. However, due to factors outside of our control, our rate lock with the lender we are currently working with has expired and the new rate that lender is offering is higher than other lenders I've found, so we intend to go with a different lender now.

Can the appraisal the first lender ordered be used by the second? Or do we have to get an appraisal ordered by the new lender?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends entirely on the new lender. In some markets, different lenders have their own favorite appraisers and don't trust other appraisers' calculations. Thus, an appraisal from Lender A's pet appraiser might not be acceptable to Lender B. Appraisals generally incorporate comparisons to recently sold similar properties in similar (or the same) neighborhoods, and the appraised value is determined in part by these comparisons. Lender B might feel that Lender A's pet appraiser didn't choose the right properties and/or the right neighborhoods (recall "Location, Location, Location" as the primary determinant of home prices?) for comparisons etc. So, it all depends.

Answer (score 2):

Usually it depends on how recent the first appraisal was. The lender will be able to tell you based on when the previous appraisal was done whether it can be used, but if it is relatively recent they should be able to use it on a refinance.

Comment: The appraisal is less than 60 days old. Would that be recent enough?

Comment: That's up to the lender to decide